# What is the Google Sync URL to choose which Google Calendars to sync?

Tags: google-calendar

You know how Google Calendar lets you have multiple calendars, i.e. weather, etc?

There is an obscure page that looks like it's designed for mobile devices that lets one choose which calendars to sync with Google Sync.

I can't seem to dig it up. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: This question is obsolete as some editions of Google Sync were retired and the question is too broad to give alternatives in few paragraphs. See [Sync Calendar with a phone or tablet - Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/151674?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén it's just here for the downvotes

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect

Comment: Thanks @g, but I don't have this question anymore. It's almost four years old. You should answer with that link though as it is a good answer.

Comment: @jonsca, why is this closed, when someone understood it and answered it? And four years later someone else found another answer to the question as seen in the comment above. It's unclear to the closers it seems. I think the more useful action would be to click the edit link and improve my question rather than close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do all the changes from: [m.google.com/sync](http://m.google.com/sync) directly from your device.

This is the actual page to select multiple calendars: [Google Sync Settings](https://m.google.com/sync/settings/iconfig/setChosenCalendars)

Comment: I see, there it is. The page looks completely different on my computer and device. It only works on my iPhone, which I replaced with a Windows Phone. I can see my Windows Phone on that page from Safari Mobile, but it says "select up to 1 calendars to sync to your device" for the WP, while the iPhone settings say "select up to 25 calendars to sync to your device". =(

 Thank you though.

Comment: For some reason, Google has made the settings page harder to find as they're preparing to phase out sync - you have to go to the second URL ( https://m.google.com/sync/settings/iconfig ) directly now - on the bright side, Windows Phone (7 and 8 ) is now allowed to sync more than 1 calendar :)

Answer (score 6):

The URL for this one has changed. Now you need to go here:

https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect

On the upside, you no longer have to be on a mobile device.

Comment: The referred URL is only for iOS devices. It is referred in th corresponding section at [Sync Calendar with a phone or tablet - Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/151674?hl=en). IMHO you could mention this as context.

Comment: iDevices & other places where a CalDAV calendar still use this service. I used it today for my Mac's calendar app. Yes, there are other ways to "make it work", but this way results in the cleanest look.

Comment: As the question doesn't mention that is about CalDav you could mention what you say as a comment in the body of your answer as context. That will make it a better answer.

Comment: As the OP doesn't mention any other target platform, I believe this answer is as valid as any other and you shouldn't be down voting just because you don't like it.

Comment: People can downvote for any reason they like, so there's no point complaining about it. It would still be better to point out that the proffered solution is for a specific platform.